# Computing Gravitational constant G from Cavendish's data

Tags: experimental-physics, gravity

I'm trying to compute the value of G from Cavendish's own observations. I get $G_{Cav}=5.27501×10^{−10}$ which is 8 times bigger than the accepted value of $G_{True}=6.67430×10^{−11}$. Do you see anything wrong with my computations below?

I'm using this formula (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavendish_experiment#Derivation_of_G_and_the_Earth%27s_mass))

$$
G = \frac{2\pi^2 L r^2 \theta}{M T^2}
$$

G = Gravitational constant

L = Length of torsion balance (the distance between the centers of balls)

r = The distance of attraction (between weights and balls)

$\theta$ = Deflection of the arm from its rest position due to gravitational attraction

M = Mass of attracting lead weight

T = Natural period of oscillation of the balance

I take $\theta$ and N from the 4th experiment, (Page 520 in [Cavendish's paper](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/pdf/10.1098/rstl.1798.0022)), the rest are constants,

L = 1.862 m

r = 0.2248 m

$r^2$ = 0.05053 $m^2$

$\theta$ = 0.00806788 radians

M = 158.04 kg

T = 421 s

$T^2$ = 177241 $s^2$

Substituting in the numbers,

$$
G_{Cav} = \frac{2 \times \pi^2 \times 1.836 \times 0.05053504 \times 0.00806788}{158.04 \times 177241} = 5.27501\times 10^{-10}
$$

This is eight times bigger than the accepted value,

$$
\frac{G_{Cav}}{G_{Tru}} = 7.90
$$

There are more details [here](http://cavendish-deneyi.com/big-g-01.html)

Comment: What values does Cavendish quote for G?

Comment: Cavedish did not compute G. G was defined about a century after his death. This answer https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/14308/16575 refers to a nice paper about the subject.

Comment: [Cross-posted to Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/710624/44126).

Comment: There are answers at [Physics Stack Exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/710624/computing-newtons-gravitational-constant-from-cavendishs-data/712292#712292).